# React Router 6, handling multiple search parameters at once

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I already used `setSearchParams` hook in Parent component , which set `query` depending on input from `input` JSX element. Now , I need to implement second search param = `sortBy` , but not to erase already or might be existing `query` search param I need to perform each time If() chech.
And also I will need if() checks in parent elements now for `sortBy` param. And potentially I might introduce few more search params in different React components - this will clutter the code.

Is there a better approach to handle multiple search params scattered through your project with React Router 6?

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const titles = ['Name', 'Sex', 'Born', 'Died', 'Father', 'Mother', 'Slug'];

export const TableHead = () => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const query = searchParams.get('query');

  return (
    <tr className="person">
      {
        titles.map(el => (
          <th
            key={el}
            onClick={() => {
              if (query) {
                setSearchParams({ query, sortBy: el.toLowerCase() });
              } else {
                setSearchParams({ sortBy: el.toLowerCase() });
              }
            }}
          >
            {el}
          </th>
        ))
      }
    </tr>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question/issue you simply want to add another query parameter to the existing queryString. You can update the current `searchParams` object and use that instead of setting the search params to an entirely new value.

Example:

```
export const TableHead = () => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const query = searchParams.get('query');

  return (
    <tr className="person">
      {titles.map(el => (
        <th
          key={el}
          onClick={() => {
            searchParams.set("sortBy": el.toLowerCase());
            setSearchParams(searchParams);
          }}
        >
          {el}
        </th>
      ))}
    </tr>
  );
};
```